# Did the Dark Tower movie adapt the whole Dark Tower book series?

Tags: book-adaptation, the-dark-tower

In the *Dark Tower* book series there are 8 books and I was wondering if the movie is covering all of them or if it is only the first one and there will be a movie for every book like in *Harry Potter*.

Comment: Practically: neither.

Answer (score 3):

No, *The Dark Tower* [film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Tower_(2017_film)) is the first film in a potential series of **SEQUEL** films and television series continuing on from the end of novels, in which due to the **nature of *The Dark Tower* mythology** (that expands into nearly every Stephen King novel), **barrows many elements and concepts** from the Dark Tower novel series.

> The Dark Tower is a 2017 American dark fantasy western film
>   directed and co-written by Nikolaj Arcel. **A continuation of Stephen
>   King's novel series of the same name**, the film stars Idris Elba as
>   Roland Deschain, a gunslinger on a quest to protect the Dark Tower—a
>   mythical structure which supports all realities—while Matthew
>   McConaughey plays his nemesis, Walter Padick, the Man in Black, and
>   Tom Taylor stars as Jake Chambers, a New York boy who becomes Roland's
>   apprentice.
>
> Intended to launch a film and television franchise, **the first
>   installment combines elements from several novels in the eight-volume
>   series, and takes place in both modern-day New York City and in
>   Mid-World, Roland's Old West-style parallel universe.** The film also
>   serves as a canonical sequel to the novel series, which concludes with
>   the revelation that Roland's quest is a cyclical time loop; the
>   presence of the Horn of Eld, which Roland carries in the film,
>   indicates that this is the next cycle.

Comment: Hmm, that's only what they would like us to think. Weak excuse for being only tangentially related to novels.

Comment: Stephen King confirmed this pretty early on and there was a huge plan for the TV series to start on NBC that has since been put back into development. I would agree that it was not a good film, but the horn pretty much gives it away that it's another iteration of the timeline(s) and I like the idea that the films/TV series wouldn't be ditto to the source material so we could see if there is "progress" made.

Comment: I still say that King saying that is only an excuse for making a mess. The idea wasn't bad, but they just didn't _really_ do it.

Comment: That I can agree with. Not a bad premise, but bad execution.

Answer (score 1):

It's sort of like an adaptation of parts of the first three books (I think). It does leave out a lot, including major characters, and it doesn't have any of the plot points, scenes, or characters from the later books.

It is likely they were planning to make a series of them but are probably not going through with that plan since the first movie was not well received.

It's more like a hot mess with some similar elements to the books.

Comment: There are some characters from later books actually, which weirded out folks before  the release. It's kind of first book mashed up with various elements of later ones like can-toi and vampires and indeed messed up.